# Python - is there a way to make all strings unicode in a project by default?

Tags: python, unicode, internationalization

Instead of typing u in front of each sting?

...and some more text to keep stackoverflow happy

Comment: You could just use python3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> s = 'hi'
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
```

In Python 3, strings are unicode strings by default.